# Generating function-unique label identifiers in inline functions with asm() calls

Tags: c

I have some `inline` function definitions which contain multiple inline `asm()` calls.  These generate branches that are resolved in *other* `asm()` calls in the same function.

There are though a couple of problems:

When the header file is invoked from the program the compiler appears to generate first a "stand alone" version of the function before the inlined code.  This gives rise to duplicate label definitions.

Q1: Is it an option to turn off this "stand alone" generation?

I cannot use a `%=` suffix on my labels as this is unique to each `asm()` call.  So I'm trying to use the preprocessor to generate a unique value:

At the top of the header

```
#ifndef CHECKED_INTEGER_ARITHMETIC_UNIQNO
#define CHECKED_INTEGER_ARITHMETIC_UNIQNO 0
#endif
```

And before each function:

```
#define CHECKED_INTEGER_ARITHMETIC_UNIQNO CHECKED_INTEGER_ARITHMETIC_UNIQNO + 1
#define UNIQNO CHECKED_INTEGER_ARITHMETIC_UNIQNO
```

And then in each `asm()` call:

```
asm(...
    "bno  nooverflow_debug_" ## UNIQNO ## " \n\t"
    ... )
```

But this gives me:

```
 error: stray '##' in program
```

I've also tried stringizing UNIQNO, but that just gives me `bno nooverflow_debug_CHECKED_INTEGER_ARITHMETIC_UNIQNO + 1` which isn't quite what I intended.

Q2:  It is possible to concatenate string literals and resolved preprocessor symbols without wrapping the entire `asm()` call in a macro to do token pasting?

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Is it an option to turn off this "stand alone" generation?

`inline extern` seems to do this.  `__attribute__((always_inline))` seems to prevent it being included back in by various options and conditions.

> Q2: ...

**Don't do this** appears to be the answer.  GCC does not support branching from one asm() section to another to give the optimiser liberty to reorder and eliminate code as per its whim.

asm goto() can branch to a C label, but cannot, as least at my compiler level, output any result, so saving the result of a operation and then directly branching dependent upon the condition code resulting from that operation appears impossible, forcing me to extract and return the CC to the surrounding code and test it there.